# Hive UDF return type array<int>

Tags: hive

Im writing a Hive UDF, based on split() GenericUDF. My function, split_int() is accepting string arguments `split_int(str,regex)` e.g. `split_int("1,2,3",",")`. I want to return `array<int>`, but instead I get `array<string>`

Code:

```
public class SplitIntUDFSplit extends GenericUDF {
     private ObjectInspectorConverters.Converter[] converters;

     @Override
     public ObjectInspector initialize(ObjectInspector[] arguments) throws UDFArgumentException {
           if (arguments.length != 2) {
              throw new UDFArgumentLengthException(
              "The function SPLIT(s, regexp) takes exactly 2 arguments.");
           }

           converters = new ObjectInspectorConverters.Converter[arguments.length];
           for (int i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
           converters[i] = ObjectInspectorConverters.getConverter(arguments[i],
                PrimitiveObjectInspectorFactory.writableStringObjectInspector);
           }
           return ObjectInspectorFactory.
            getStandardListObjectInspector(PrimitiveObjectInspectorFactory.writableIntObjectInspector);
     }

     @Override
     public Object evaluate(DeferredObject[] arguments) throws HiveException {
         assert (arguments.length == 2);

           if (arguments[0].get() == null || arguments[1].get() == null) {
               return null;
           }

           Text s = (Text) converters[0].convert(arguments[0].get());
           Text regex = (Text) converters[1].convert(arguments[1].get());

           ArrayList<IntWritable> result = new ArrayList<IntWritable>();


           for (String str : s.toString().split(regex.toString())) {
                  result.add(new IntWritable(Integer.parseInt(str)));
           }
           return result;
     }
```

How to make the udf return `array<int>`?

Comment: The last line of your initialize method seems pretty obviously correct to me... that makes me think it's not a problem with your code but instead with how you've loaded it into hive. Maybe you've got an old version of the jar floating around somewhere? Do a fresh build, re-upload it to wherever hive is adding it from, make sure there's no other versions that could be on the classpath (`find / -name "whatever.jar"`), etc. Also, can you post specifically how you're calling the UDF?

Comment: Im using cloudera's Hue panel to add UDF jar (CDH4.4). I tried calling the UDF split_int("1,2,3",",") and it returned array ["1","2","3"] of type array<string>. I tried hardcoding result.add(new IntWritable(1)); for the funcion call above and I got ["1","1","1"] string array...

Comment: @JoeK You were right, restarting Hive and Hue resolved the issue and I am getting expected results.